# hadoop setup method mapper

Tags: hadoop, iteration, distributed

I'm currently trying to learn hadoop programming and writing the program that deals with two input source within one mapper. This work is similar with the mapside-join problem.

so, I firstly used the distributed cache, however, it does not work well.
Thus I secondly used the setup() function. It works well in local execution mode on a single PC, however, it does not work in a cluster environment.

I don't know the reason exactly.

Is there any configuration of a cluster if we use the setup() function?

And the following is a part of my code. This part is the job driver which embodies a iteration work.

```
public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int iteration = 1;

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Path in = new Path(arg0[0]);
    Path out = new Path(arg0[1]+"iteration_"+iteration);

    conf.set("conf.threshold", arg0[2]);

    Job job = new Job(conf, "Test");
    job.setJarByClass(getClass());
    job.setMapperClass(FirstMap.class);
    job.setReducerClass(FirstReduce.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, in);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);
    job.waitForCompletion(true);


    // start second job

//  long counter = 4;//job.getCounters().findCounter(SecondReduce.Counter.CONVERGED).getValue();
    String PriorPath = out.toString();

    boolean Updates = true;
    while (Updates) {

        iteration ++;
        conf = new Configuration();

        Path out2 = new Path(arg0[1]+"iteration_"+iteration);

        conf.set("prior.job.out", PriorPath);
        conf.set("conf.iteration", iteration+"");
        job = new Job(conf, "job"+iteration);
        job.setJarByClass(getClass());
        job.setMapperClass(SecondMap.class);
        job.setReducerClass(SecondReduce.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);


        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, in);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out2);
        job.waitForCompletion(true);

        PriorPath = out2.toString();

        long counter = job.getCounters().findCounter(Counter.CONVERGED).getValue();
        Updates = (counter > 0);
        System.out.println("counter : " + counter);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also the mapper including the setup function is as follows.

```
public static class SecondMap extends
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    Vector<String> Vec = new Vector<String>();
    Vector<String> Gen = new Vector<String>();
    int iteration;
    @Override
    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        super.setup(context);
        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        Path Cand = new Path(conf.get("prior.job.out"));
    //  iteration = Integer.parseInt(conf.get("conf.iteration"));
        String iter = conf.get("conf.iteration");
        iteration = Integer.parseInt(iter);

        try {
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
            FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(Cand);
            for (int i = 0; i < status.length; i++) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(fs.open(status[i].getPath())));
                String line;
                line = br.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);

                    Vec.add(line);
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
        Gen = GenerateCandidate(Vec, iteration);

    }

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // something with CandGen

        }
    }
}
```

Anyone who has experience about this problem?

Comment: What do you mean your setup function doesn't work? What is happening? Also, you shouldn't try to avoid the distributed cache because it doesn't seem to work well. It works just fine for most of us.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. To not work the setup function means the value intended to be store into "Vec" is nothing in a cluster although it works well in a PC (I did a simple test with the same program and input).

Comment: Also, when using the distributed cache, this application works if I input path for cache via command. It means that modifying the paths in a program makes the result to which I not intended.

Answer (score 0):

It's called per Mapper task or Reducer task only once. So if 10 mappers or reducers were spawned for a job, then for each mapper and reducer it will be called once.
General guidelines for what to add in this method, is any task that is required to do once can be written here, e.g. getting path of Distributed cache, Passing and getting parameters to mappers and reducers.
Similar is for cleanup method.